# Why is writing the same data to IndexedDB a second time consistently slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, blob, indexeddb

I stored some jpeg files (exactly 350, same files same size. Total: 336.14 MB) as `Blob` in IndexedDB. It took around 1 second to complete the transaction. Then I read all the **data from IndexedDB** to an array and again sored to IndexedDB. But this time it takes around 15 Seconds. I observed this as a consistent behavior. Anything wrong here? I used `performance.now()` to get the time difference

Files: 350,
Size of each: 937 KB,
Browser: Chrome and Chromium Edge

```
    //Open
var dbOpen = indexedDB.open(INDEXED_DB_NAME, INDEXED_DB_VERSION);
dbOpen.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    console.log("onupgradeneeded");
    var store = e.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
        IMAGE_DATA_STORE, { autoIncrement: true });
};
dbOpen.onsuccess = function (e) {
    image_data_db = dbOpen.result;
    console.log("indexed DB opened");
};
//Initial Write
    var inputFiles = document.getElementById('inputFiles');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.files.length; i++) {
        let file = inputFiles.files[i];
        var b = new Blob([file], { type: file.type });
        fileblobs.push(b);
    }
    StoreIdb(fileblobs); // < First write
    
//StoreIdb()

    t0 = performace.now(); 
    var trx = image_data_db.transaction(IMAGE_DATA_STORE, 'readwrite');
    var imagestore = trx.objectStore(IMAGE_DATA_STORE);
    for (i = 0; i < fileblobs.length; i++) {
        request = imagestore.add(fileblobs[i]);
        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            console.log('added');
        };
        request.onerror = function (e) {
            console.error("Request Error", this.error);
        };
    }
    trx.onabort = function (e) {
        console.error("Exception:", this.error, this.error.name);
    };
    trx.oncomplete = function (e) {
        console.log('completed');
        t1 = performance.now();
        timetaken = t1 - t0; 
    }
        
//Read
    var objectStore = image_data_db.transaction(IMAGE_DATA_STORE).objectStore(IMAGE_DATA_STORE);
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function (e) {
        var cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
           blobArray.push(cursor.value.blob); 
           cursor.continue();
        }
        else
        {
            // completed 
        }
    }

// blobArray will be used for second time << Second Write
```

Comment: how are you timing it?  many things happen in callbacks, and lots of important information in your question is missing from the code you have provided

Comment: I am storing everything in a single transaction. So i get time before transaction starts and inside trx.oncomplete function.

Comment: I ve changed this to
 for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.files.length; i++) {
        let file = inputFiles.files[i];
        var b = new Blob([file], { type: file.type });
        fileblobs.push(b);
    }
this
let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(e.target.result)], {type: 'image/bmp'});

Now it taking same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. First time it was storing file instance blob.
I ve changed file instance blob to Array buffer just to want to ensure data type similar in both cases. Now it is taking same time.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.files.length; i++) {
    let file = inputFiles.files[i];
    file.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
        let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], {type: file.type });
        blobs.push(blob);
        if ( blobs.length == inputFiles.files.length){
            callback(blobs);
        }
    });
}
```